# Regex to NOT match exact words in a string

Tags: regex

I've the following string:

```
group.cluster.namespace.release.app.pod.timer.grpc.server.processing.duration.package.method.error.count
```

and a regex:

```
(?:[^.]+\.){11}([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.(?:[^.]+)
```

that [produces a match](https://regex101.com/r/Z6Kota/1):

```
Group 1: package
Group 2: method
Group 3: error
```

Now I want to *not match* when group 3 is either `ok` or `cancelled`. I tried a negative lookahead, but it's not working.

```
(?:[^.]+\.){11}([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.(?!ok|cancelled)\.(?:[^.]+)
```

What is wrong with the regex above?

Comment: Should it be like this? https://regex101.com/r/5T1z68/1

Comment: What about `(\w+)\.(\w+)\.(?!ok\.|cancelled\.)(\w+)\.\w+$`. Or do you need to start matching from the start perse? And...is the `\w+` metacharacter proficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your pattern with the negative lookahead, you have to match any char except a dot again in a group.

I would also suggest using wordboundaries to prevent partial matches, and perhaps add an anchor `^` to assert the start of the string.

Note that the negated character classes `[^.]+` can also match across newlines. You can exclude newlines using `[^.\r\n]+`

```
(?:[^.]+\.){11}([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.(?!ok\b|cancelled\b)([^.]+)\.(?:[^.]+)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k9i4fX/1).